# Angular UI Bootstrap4 Vertical Tabs

Tags: angularjs, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap

my code:

```
<uib-tabset class="tabs-left" vertical="true">
    <uib-tab heading="Basic" active="tabs[0].active"> 
    FIRST Tab </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab heading="Template" active="tabs[1].active"> 
    SECOND Tab </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

It is generating tabs in horizontal. but i require vertical, can any one please let me know how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding below line in css it is displaying vertically.

```
.nav-stacked {
    display: block;
}
```